# What should I use for the first parameter of the .apply() method when calling it within an XMLHttpRequest?

Tags: javascript, ajax, apply

I'm trying to write a function which will act on an array of data passed into it using AJAX. It's not doing anything, and the last thing left that I can find that I might be doing wrong is the first parameter of my `.apply()` call (i.e. the owner of my `underlyingFunction()` method).

Here's my code:

```
function XMLfunction(targetElement,param1,param2) {
    var workingArray = new Array(targetElement);
    var request;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else {
        request = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    request.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
            var parser = new DOMParser();
            var xml = parser.parseFromString(this.responseText,"text/xml");
            for (var i = 0; i < xml.childNodes[0].childNodes.length; i++) {
                workingArray.push(xml.childNodes[0].childNodes[i].innerHTML);
            }
            alert (workingArray); // workingArray looks exactly like it's supposed to
            underlyingFunction().apply(this,workingArray);  // underlyingFunction() works perfectly when called directly in a script
            alert ("applied"); // XMLfunction() stops before it gets to this line
        }
    }
    request.open("GET","myURL.php?param1="+param1+"&param2="+param2,true);
    request.send();
}
```

The first parameter of `.apply()` here is `this`, but I have tried using `document` and, out of desperation, `window` as well.  What should it be?  Or what else am I doing wrong?

Comment: `underlyingFunction().apply(this,workingArray);` **calls** `underlyingFunction` and then tries to use `apply` on its return value. If you're trying to call `underlyingFunction` passing each of the array elements to it as a discrete argument, remove the `()` after `underlyingFunction` (and probably use `undefined` instead of `this`, but if `underlyingFunction` doesn't use `this` it doesn't matter): `underlyingFunction.apply(undefined, workingArray);` Or alternatively, in modern JavaScript, `underlyingFunction(...workingArray);`

Comment: (Voted to close as typo/non-repro.)

Comment: If you just want to call it with the array, it's `underlyingFunction(workingArray);`, but from your use of `apply` I'm guessing you wanted the elements as discrete arguments.